# How this code works in python?

Tags: python

Why it prints 5 when I execute a[False] and prints 6 when a[True]?

```
a = [5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[True]) #prints 6
print(a[False]) #prints 5
```

Comment: `True` and `False` are not only boolean values but integers. Check it with `print(isinstance(True, int))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python when you try to access True/False in list as index it will consider True=1 and False=0.

As a result when you wrote `a[True]` it actually means `a[1]` and `a[False]` means `a[0]`. To clarify this try `a[-True]` it will interpret it as `a[-1]` and print 9

```
a = [5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[True]) #prints 6
print(a[False]) #prints 5
print(a[-True]) #prints 9
```

Comment: This "when you try to pass True/False in list argument" is misleading. First it is not an argument and second this is not limited to a list index because `True` and `False` not only behave as integers, they are integers.

Answer (score 3):

In this context True = 1 and False = 0. This means that if you put

```
your_list[True]
```

you're retrieving the item of your list with index 1. Similarly,

```
your_list[False]
```

returns the the item of your list with index 0.

Answer (score 2):

`print (a[True])` print 6 because the value of True is 1 and then `a[1]` is whereasas the value of false is 0 and `a[0]` is 5.

Comment: Use formatting when writing answers. This time I have done it for you, but next time do that yourself it will be easy to read if you format it correctly